# What is an "acceptable" return value from cv::calibrateCamera?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

**Background:**

I'm currently working on a stereo vision project using OpenCV. I'm trying to create a disparity map from a set of two rectified images, but I'm not getting the result I expect. When looking at the rectified images, there is a noticeable *vertical shift* between the images, which should not be there after rectification. I'm currently looking for what the error may be. My code is based on the stereo calibration and correspondence code from the OpenCV book, and [this example](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stereo_match.cpp). I use the C++ interface of OpenCV. My OpenCV version is 2.1, from the Ubuntu 11.04 repository.

**Short version of question:**

What RMS return value is acceptable for the function:

```
double cv::calibrateCamera(...)
```

I currently calibrate each camera using a set of ~20 chessboard image pairs. The cameras are two identical PS3 Eyes (with a resolution of 640*480 pixels) mounted beside each other. `cv::calibrateCamera` returns an RMS error of between **160** and **300** (I've had different result with different image sets). Is this an acceptable value for this image resolution or should I attempt to get better chessboard images?

**Long version (details, code samples):**

To get working stereo vision; first, I want to be sure the camera calibration routine works correctly. I use a series of chessboard images to calibrate my stereo setup, like so:

```
// Find chessboard corners
cv::Mat left = ... //Load image
vector<cv::Point2f> points;

bool found = cv::findChessboardCorners(left, patternSize, points, CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);
if(found)
  cv::cornerSubPix(left, points, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1), cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));
imagePointsLeft.push_back(points);
```

I do this for a number of image pairs and put the resulting points in `imagePointsLeft` and `imagePointsRight`. I have run a check in a separate program on the same images where I visually confirm that the left and right images correctly register all corners, in the same order, using `cv::drawChessboardCorners`. For each image pair I also fill a set of object coordinates like so:

```
vector<cv::Point3f> obj;
for(int i = 0; i < ny; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < nx; j++)
    obj.push_back(cv::Point3f(i*squareSize,j*squareSize,0.0));
objectPoints.push_back(obj);
```

I then attempt to calibrate the cameras with these images:

```
double rms = cv::calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePointsLeft, m_imageSize, m_cameraMatrixLeft, m_distortionMatrixLeft, rvecsLeft, tvecsLeft);
```

I use the camera intrinsics from this function when I call `cv::stereoCalibrate` using the flag `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` (this way of stereo calibration is suggested in the documentation, [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/calib3d_camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereoCalibrate)).

I proceed to call `cv::stereoRectify` and `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap`, the latter for both cameras. The rectified images are produced with `cv::remap` using the output of `initUndistortRectifyMap` and a camera livefeed. Both images contain only valid pixels (no black areas). My problem is that the pixels of a given row does not match the same row in the other image (there is a slight vertical offset). This makes it difficult to get any good results from correspondence algorithms such as StereoBM.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a problem with your camera calibration: `cv::calibrateCamera()` returns the root mean square (RMS) reprojection error [1] and should be between 0.1 and 1.0 pixels in a good calibration. For a point of reference, I get approximately 0.25 px RMS error using my custom stereo camera made of two hardware-synchronized Playstation Eye cameras running at the 640 x 480 resolution.

Are you sure that the pixel coordinates returned by `cv::findChessboardCorners()` are in the same order as those in `obj`? If the axes were flipped, you would get symptoms similar to those that you are describing.

[1]: OpenCV calculates reprojection error by projecting three-dimensional of chessboard points into the image using the final set of calibration parameters and comparing the position of the corners. An RMS error of 300 means that, on average, each of these projected points is 300 px away from its actual position.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Now I know what to look for. I will try some different setups when taking calibration images.

Comment: @Michael: did you mean cv::calibrateCamera()? findChessboardCorners() doesn't return an error value.

Comment: @neuviemeporte Yes, you're absolutely right. I've corrected my original post.

Comment: @MichaelKoval where are you getting this range - 0.1 to 1.0? I have trouble getting better than 1.3.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer this isn't a hard and fast rule. In practice, I have found that a good calibration gives me sub pixel reproduction error. The actual error you can achieve depends an enormous about on your camera and the type of lens you are using (i.e. whether it matches one of OpenCV's distortion models).

Comment: Could you expand on a common camera like the one found in the iPhone 5S? I'm working with smartphones in general and I am trying to figure these things including test methodology and what is the reasonable range of expectation.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really not sure. The number is an average reproduction error in pixels and the range of acceptable values depends on your application. That being said, the numbers I quoted are from a pretty high-end Prosilica camera. I wouldn't be surprised if you are getting worse results from a smartphone.